# Is it possible to make this non repainting one with having same results on live chart?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

```
/@version=5
indicator(title='Simple Buy/Sell', overlay=true)

//Signals
buy = (high > open[1]) and not (low < open[1])
sell = (low < open[1]) and not (high > open[1])

//Plots
plotshape(buy, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny)
```

Is there a way to make non repaint signals on live charts without using

```
buy = (high[1] > open[2]) and not (low[1] < open[2])
sell = (low[1] < open[2]) and not (high[1] > open[2])
```

I tried many things but nothing works like the above script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `barstate.isconfirmed` built-in variable. That will wait until the bar is closed and then evaluate your condition.

> Returns true if the script is calculating the last (closing) update of
> the current bar. The next script calculation will be on the new bar
> data.

Comment: Thanks for this but the result varies when i use `barstate.isconfirmed`

Comment: What do you mean?